# Windows 10 to Windows 7 Downgrade: BCD error when trying to boot from W7 bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb, bcd

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my laptop which currently has 10. The bootable USB I made works fine on my desktop. If I install from the windows 10 partition using the setup.exe file, it goes through fine until the reboot. It will open the new "Windows Setup" boot option from Windows Boot Manager, but gets hung up on disk.sys (according to safe mode) and won't do anything.

If I try and boot directly from the USB it gives the error about bcd:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcd

  Status: 0xc0000225
```

However I'm sure you can see the trouble in that this IS the repair disk (essentially). I tried to remake the BCD file on my Windows 7 desktop according to [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/628038/boot-bcd-status-0xc000000f-error) while replacing the final command with 
`bcdboot c:\windows /s h:` because all that stuff seemed to do is completely remove the boot folder.

Lemme know what you think my next steps should be, I've fiddled with it as much as I care to before I break something!

Comment: In order to downgrade to Windows 7 from Windows 10, you have to format the HDD ( I.e. delete all partitions on the HDD), then install Windows 7.  Have you done that?

Comment: @Ramhound No I was trying to avoid that just because I like having all the old files in the Windows.OLD folder in addition to normal backup. If that's the case then that's what I'll do.

I also have Linux Mint on the hard drive so I'm sure that was making it even harder.

Comment: There is no way to downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 7 that generates a Windows.old.  That folder is only generated if you do installation of the same  version of Windows or upgrade to a newer version.